# A DLL working good in my project but when i change it to windows service not working

Tags: c#, windows, dll, service, hl7

I have a Windows Service (in C#). This program interacts with an external DLL that has a method that returns an HL7 object and i sending it a datetime parametre.when i call this medhod from this dll,I get an exception like

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: MHRS_WINDOWS.MHRS_Biz.CheckShedule_XML(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)

This method is working fine when i call it as a different project.but when i make it windows service, i get that exception.
I have no idea about this difference.

This is why?

Is there something I can do to make sure the DLL call works as intended?

Comment: What is the exception message? The stack trace?

Comment: It looks like the issue may have something to do with an issue of DateTime conversion, however, without the exception message or stack trace I can't be of much more help...  Please post this when you have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you are doing the DateTime parsing using the default locale, and the default locale is different in the user profile and in the system profile (used in the service).